# Carrot2-bisectingKmeans setting the attribute of resouceLookup causes the error of no resouces named stopwords.ar

Tags: k-means, multilingual, carrot2

Carrot2-I tried to cluster docs through the bisectingKmeans algorithm.
I set the attribute of resouceLookup and tested the language of English/Chinese. It both resulted in the error "no resouces named stopwords.ar in resouce lookup locations...". 
The cod I wrote:

```
//set the resoucelookup
File resDir = new File("resouces");
ResouceLookup res = new ResouceLookup(new DirLocator(resDir));
LexicalDataLoaderDescriptor.attributeBuilder(preprocessAttr).resourceLookup(res);
//set the language
MultilingualClusteringDescriptor.attributeBuilder(processingAttr)
            .defaultLanguage(LanguageCode.CHINESE_SIMPLIFIED);
```

What's the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most explicit way to solve this would be to copy all all lexical resources to your `resources` directory. You can find the resource files in [Carrot2 Java API distribution](http://project.carrot2.org/download.html), for example.

An alternative is to tell Carrot2 to load the missing resources from the classpath (Carrot2 JAR):

```
File resourcesDir = new File("resources");
ResourceLookup resourceLookup = new ResourceLookup(
    new DirLocator(resourcesDir),   // your custom location
    new ContextClassLoaderLocator() // fallback: classpath (Carrot2 JAR)
);
LexicalDataLoaderDescriptor.attributeBuilder(attrs)
    .resourceLookup(resourceLookup);
```

In this arrangement, your `resources` directory can only contain the resources you'd like to override. The non-overridden ones (and the ones that you don't care about) will be loaded from Carrot2 JAR.

There are two **caveats** here:

- When you upgrade Carrot2 JAR, the fallback resources may silently change.
- In case of a misconfigured custom location (e.g. passing an empty directory), clustering will silently proceed with built-in lexical resources without any specific warning (unless you use the debug logging level).

Answer (score 0):

Copying all the resources is a better idea and the reason why there is no default fallback -- you will have complete control over what resources are present and for which language. This is important because resources are merged by default http://download.carrot2.org/head/manual/index.html#section.attribute.kmeans.merge-resources